# Reading from Excel File

Tags: c#, database, oledb

I have seen many examples of this around but something isn't working for me.

What I am looking to do is to read an Excel sheet, given a sheet and store those values into Lists.

For example, say I have an excel file that looks like:

```
First   Second  Third
f1      s1      t1
f2      s2      t2
f3      s3      t3
```

Each row is to be considered a set of values.

This is what I have doing so far:

```
List<string> ColumnNames= GetColumnNames();

        using (OleDbConnection OleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(Path))
        {
            OleDbConn.Open();
            String cmdString = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName+ "]";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdString, OleDbConn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            List<ValueSet> sets = new List<ValueSet>();
            Dictionary<string, Value> values = new Dictionary <string,value>()
            ValueSet valueset = new ValueSet(null);
            using (OleDbDataReader oleRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (oleRdr.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnNames.Count; i++)
                    {
                        ColumnName cn = new ColumnName(columnNames[i]);

                        string data= oleRdr[f.Name].ToString();
                        Value value = new Value(data, f);

                        if (!values.ContainsKey(ColumnNames[i]))
                        {
                            values.Add(ColumnNames[i], value);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            values[ColumnNames[i]] = value;
                        }
                    }
                    valueSet= new ValueSet(values);
                    sets.Add(valueSet);
                }
                return sets;;
            }
```

Comment: I suggest putting breaking points every time you set values. Step through the code and watch how your sets.Add(valueSet) is being called.

Comment: I've stepped through the code multiple times, I still don't see how to modify my values. If you forget for a second all my objects and I asked you to do this with `List<List<strings>>` How would you go about it? @RezaShirazian

Comment: Your code is a little hard to read, you make a datatable, then a dictionary, put values in the dictionary then pass the dictionary to the `valueset` object, then add `valuesets` to a list. Overall I would suggest going back and re-doing the whole thing from the ground up, break down the problem into smaller steps and don't make it overly complicated. Start small like add only one column through each iteration. As you get the small pieces working, build on it. Also don't be afraid to use `Debug.WriteLine()` to keep track of how your code is behaving

Comment: @RezaShirazian I've done this method over what seems like a million times. I'll try again, breaking it down as much as possible. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten weird results with certain files using an `OleDbConnection`.

I suggest http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11698/A-Portable-and-Efficient-Generic-Parser-for-Flat-F

With this you can read your CSV into a datatable and parse it into a list as follows:

```
DataTable dtPrereg;

using (GenericParserAdapter gp = new GenericParserAdapter(Server.MapPath("prereg.csv"), Encoding.UTF8))
{
    gp.FirstRowHasHeader = true;
    dtPrereg = gp.GetDataTable();
}
```

I haven't tested this on tab delimited files, but it should work the same (or you could convert your file to CSV)

Answer (score 1):

If you really have a spreadsheet with a known number of  named columns and you want to project them into a `List<List<string>>` it's a lot easier to just do it with Linq.

e.g.

```
List<List<string>> data;

using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    data = (from row in rdr.Cast<DbDataRecord>()
            select new List<string>
            {
                row["First"].ToString(),
                row["Second"].ToString(),
                row["Third"].ToString()
            }).ToList();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
 ValueSet= new ValueSet(values);
 sets.Add(ValueSet);
```

to

```
valueset = new ValueSet(values);
sets.Add(valueset );
```